# Is it possible to implement 3d touch on UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9.1

I am new to iOS development, but I need to implement 3d touch on UIButton, when user apply force on a button shortcut menu would pop out, even if someone could just provide me the sample code in ObjectiveC for 3d touch would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the code provided by apple in their iOS 9.1 changelog? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016572-SW1

Comment: Yes, I have looked into it but the problem is all the sample code are in swift and I have tried to find these in Objective C but its not working according to my need secondly, simulator also does not supports 3d touch now so I need perfect code just to save some of my time, if you could just provide me the structure of using 3d touch in Objective that would be great help.

Comment: @HarryNg I'm in the same predicament as Abdul.  Yes, you can have apps that run both Obj-C and Swift, but a lot of the code for the 3D Touch has to be implemented in the AppDelegate, so you either convert every line of code in that file, or come up with a way to bring in 3D Touch using Obj-C.  He is right that all sample codes are Swift...your comment kind of stinks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, I've a demonstration of how to detect 3d touch on a `UIButton` in a sample application on github below. For the menu popup portion I will leave that to you to implement but this will get you the force/3d touch piece.

https://github.com/foggzilla/DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer

The way I'm doing this is to use a [DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/foggzilla/DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer) that I have made available in the sample project.

The `DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer` provides continuous updates about the pressure changes so you can do nice things like transform the button as the user varies their pressure on it, as opposed to a single event. If you just want a single event you can ignore eveything in the `DFContinuousForceTouchDelegate` except the `- (void) forceTouchRecognized` callback.

You can download this and run the sample app on a device that supports force press to see how it feels.

**In your UIViewController implement:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _forceTouchRecognizer = [[DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    _forceTouchRecognizer.forceTouchDelegate = self;

    [self.button addGestureRecognizer:_forceTouchRecognizer];
}
```

**implement the delegate protocol for force touch:**

```
#pragma DFContinuousForceTouchDelegate

- (void)forceTouchRecognized:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.button setNeedsDisplay];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Force Touch Button" message:@"YEAH!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    });
}
- (void)forceTouchRecognizer:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer didStartWithForce:(CGFloat)force maxForce:(CGFloat)maxForce {
    CGFloat transformDelta = 1.0f + ((force/maxForce) / 3.0f);
    self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(transformDelta, transformDelta);
    [self.button setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)forceTouchRecognizer:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer didMoveWithForce:(CGFloat)force maxForce:(CGFloat)maxForce {
    CGFloat transformDelta = 1.0f + ((force/maxForce) / 3.0f);
    self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(transformDelta, transformDelta);
    [self.button setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)forceTouchRecognizer:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer didCancelWithForce:(CGFloat)force maxForce:(CGFloat)maxForce  {
    self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.button setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)forceTouchRecognizer:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer didEndWithForce:(CGFloat)force maxForce:(CGFloat)maxForce {
    self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.button setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)forceTouchDidTimeout:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.button setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Note that this will only be useful on a device that supports force touch.

Also you should not add the `DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer` to a view if are you running on iOS8 or under since it uses the new `force` property on `UITouch` only available in iOS9.

If you add this on iOS8 it will crash, so conditionally add this recognizer based on what iOS version you are running on if you are supporting versions older than iOS 9.

Comment: is any of this available in swift?

Comment: The library is in Objective C, but I don't see why it shouldn't work through bridging.

Answer (score 9):

You can overload `UIButton` and examine the `force` property on the `UITouch`es in

`- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`

`- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`

Based on what happens here, you could send your own custom action for force touches, with:

`- (void)sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;`